# Knockoutjs super basics

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable, subscribe

I am trying to accomplish the following task:

1. List item
2. Get a twitter handle
3. Ask user how many tweets to display
4. Fetch tweets
5. Display only the tweets the user has specified

I have a super basic problem. I have hard coded html and I can fetch tweets with knockouk, I'd like to eliminate my hardcoded element and only use knockoutjs. I can fetch x number of tweets from user Y using **subscribe** and I use the **observable array** to push tweets into.

**Code that works fantastic**. Here is how I do it:

```
TwitterGet = function() {
  var recent_tweets = ko.observableArray();
  var twitter_image = ko.observable();

  var component = this;  
  var url = 'https://twitter.com/search.json?callback=?';

  this.attributes.twitter_user_handle.subscribe(function(value) {

    var url = 'https://twitter.com/search.json?callback=?';
    var twitter_parameters = {
      include_entities: true,
      include_rts: true,
      q: 'from:' + value,   
      count: '3'
    }

  $.getJSON(url,twitter_parameters, 
  function(json) {
    twitter_image(json.results[0].profile_image_url);
      result = json.results;
      recent_tweets.push(result);
  });
 }); 
};
```

My problem is uber simple. The tweets live here:

1. recent_tweets.slice(-1)[0][0].text (first tweet)
2. recent_tweets.slice(-1)[0][1].text (second tweet)

Right now I am statically plugging each tweet into html. This breaks if the user only has 3 tweets and I have hard coded 5 tweets into the html. How can I user knockout to insert html with the tweet?

**Example of STATIC HTML that I would like to eliminate, AND replace with dynamic HTML inserted by Knockout JS.**

```
<div class="tweet" id="first-tweet">
<span class="handle"><a href="#" target="_blank" data-bind-component_<%=component.id-%>="inline_edit: attributes.twitter_user_handle"></a> 
</span><span data-bind-component_<%=component.id-%>="inline_edit: recent_tweets.slice(-1)[0][1].text"></span><br>
<a href="#">share</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">retweet</a> 
<a href="#">reply</a></div>

<div class="tweet" id="second-tweet">
<span class="handle"><a href="#" target="_blank" data-bind-component_<%=component.id-%>="inline_edit: attributes.twitter_user_handle"></a> 
</span><span data-bind-component_<%=component.id-%>="inline_edit: recent_tweets.slice(-1)[0][2].text"></span><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea would be to use the `foreach` binding of Knockout with an observbaleArray.  Rather than pushing the result into the observableArray, you would want to set it entirely to a new array.

So, instead of:

```
recent_tweets.push(result);
```

You would do:

```
recent_tweets(result);
```

Here is a sample based on your code that exposes some of the observables for binding: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/8kK6m/